# Is it possible to trully force a variable to become constant to allow me declaring arrays dynamically?

Tags: c, loops, constants

I did some googling and I'm pretty sure this is impossible in C, as constants are created during the compiling..

Anyways, I would still like to ask it it's possible. I would like to generate arrays in a loop with loop defined length like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWCOL_MULTIPLIER 50
main() {
    for (int loop = 0; loop < 11; loop++) {
        const int val = loop * ROWCOL_MULTIPLIER;
        double b[val] = malloc(sizeof(double)* val * val);

        // do foo things

        free(b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I needed to accomplish http://ideone.com/fork/TyGZVV

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWCOL_MULTIPLIER 1
main() {
    size_t loop, i, j = 0;
    for (loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++) {
        const double val = (loop + 1) * ROWCOL_MULTIPLIER;
        double *column_sum = malloc(val * sizeof *column_sum);
        double *p = malloc(val * val * sizeof *p);

        printf("\n%i\n", loop + 1);

        for (i = 0; i < val; ++i){
            column_sum[i] = *(double*)&i;
            for (j = 0; j < val; ++j){
                int index = i * (int)val + j;
                p[index] = *(double*)&j;

                double offsetI = column_sum[i];
                double offsetJ = p[index]++;

                printf("%d->", offsetI);
                printf("%d,", offsetJ);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        free(p);
        free(column_sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good style, to put a `const` declaration inside a loop like that?  What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: Robert Harvey♦, meaning that even though my `val` is declared as `const`, next line wouldn't accept it as `const`, and giving me an error `expected constant expression`

Comment: The problem with your “not working” line is that you forgot to specify the type of `val`.  The `const` is fine.

Comment: You *intended* to declare a VLA of *pointers* with `double *b[val]` ?

Comment: Still was tweaking the code. There.

Comment: You also forgot the return type of `main`, which should be `int`.

Comment: And also the `return` from `main`.

Comment: And if you want to use `malloc` and `free`, you'll need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @ericbn, This might be it! Let me see.

Comment: @AlexD This would be true if it were C++.  But it's C.

Comment: @ericbn your code is wrong, to refer to an array of `doubles` you should use `double *`. (If you try anything like `b[1][2]` your program will crash)

Comment: @ericbn your code does not allocate such a thing

Comment: @ericbn you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`b[0]`). This causes undefined behaviour. It may crash, or it may appear to work until your next presentation

Comment: @ericbn anyway, Robert Harvey will surely come and delete all these comments soon; if you have an answer the post an answer

Comment: @MattMcNabb, apologies for my wrong (and spamming) comments. Your answer and http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html helped me understand what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C89, `double b[val]` is illegal, because a `const` variable does not count as a compile-time constant.

In any version of C, `double b[val] = malloc`... is illegal because an array can only be initialized by values matching its element type. An array of doubles can contain things like `3.1`, `7.2` - not `malloc`.

In C99 you can write:

```
double b[val];
```

which is an array of `val` doubles. If you want `val * val` doubles you can write `double b[val * val];`, or `double b[val][val];` or anything else along those lines.  This array uses automatic storage (sometimes called *stack*) and is freed when the code block including this definition ends.

In any version of C you can use dynamic storage. In that case you must use a pointer to refer to the storage, e.g.:

```
double *p = malloc( val * sizeof *p );

double *p = malloc( val * val * sizeof *p );
```

In C99 you can combine malloc with variably-modified types, this will let you use 2-D array access syntax:

```
double (*p)[val] = malloc(val * sizeof *p);

for (size_t i = 0; i < val; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < val; ++j)
        p[i][j] = 0.0;
```

Comment: Inside inner loop with line "column_sum[i] += p[j][i];" i get an error saying "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". http://ideone.com/nTqSoX Would you know why, by any chance?

Comment: @HelpNeeder in your code `column_sum` is a pointer to double, so you cannot dereference it twice. If you are allocating a 1-D array of size `val * val` then you need to access it via `p[row * val + col]`

Comment: Also you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: "double(*p)[val] = malloc(val * sizeof *p);" won't also compile, it asks for a static "var". :/

Comment: @HelpNeeder make sure you are using a C99 compiler to try that option. Your original code suggests you may not be, `main()` is illegal in C99

Comment: I think I have C99, only C99 allows `prog.c:18:4: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`. This is what I was working on. http://ideone.com/fork/TyGZVV Thanks for help, again.

Comment: @HelpNeeder if you get an error message "X is only allowed in C99 mode" it's because you are not actually in C99 mode. Otherwise you wouldn't get the error. Try choosing "C99 strict" on ideone, or use a different site such as coliru which lets you give the compiler options. I guess that ideone's "C" uses gcc's default mode, which is C89 plus GNU extensions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference between a compile-time constant and a `const` variable:  The compile-time constant can (duh!) be computed at compile time.  For the C compiler, this means that the amount of space that must be reserved for an array of size X can be computed if X is a compile-time constant.  If X is simply `const` then amount of space to reserve for the array cannot be known at compile time.

Since the C compiler essentially creates a `struct` for each automatic storage frame, and since the size of all the elements of a `struct` must be known at compile time, if you want to declare an array that is allocated in automatic storage it must have a size that is a compile-time constant.  Similarly, if you want to declare an array that is allocated as a part of a `struct` or `class`, its size must be known at compile time.